# Configuring Bison and Flex without global or static variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, bison, flex-lexer

i am working in a small language/IDE. And I need to know how to configure flex and bison to work together but without using any global or static variable. I need to pass to bison my AST pointer. I also need that bison pass my AST to flex as well. It's a thread environment but i dont need any thread sync. And I need a separete yylineno variable for each yyparse() call. I read about %define api.pure , %parse-param and %option reentrant. But i don't know how to put them to work together... thx in advance...

I tried this:

scanner.l:

```
%{

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "parser.tab.h"
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex(YYSTYPE * lvalp, yyscan_t scanner)
extern void yyerror(yyscan_t scanner, NBloco * bloco, const char *s);

%}

%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%option reentrant 
%option bison-bridge

%%
//...scanner code
```

parser.y:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include "AST.h"

#ifndef YY_TYPEDEF_YY_SCANNER_T
#define YY_TYPEDEF_YY_SCANNER_T
typedef void* yyscan_t;
#endif

extern "C" int yylex(YYSTYPE * lvalp, yyscan_t scanner);
extern "C" FILE *yyin;
extern int yylineno;
void yyerror(yyscan_t scanner, NBloco * bloco, const char *s);
%}

%union{ 
//union code
}

%define api.pure full
%lex-param   { yyscan_t scanner }
%parse-param { yyscan_t scanner }
%parse-param { NBlock* block}

//tokens...
//types...

%%

//parser code...
```

And I got this:

```
parser.y:13:22: warning: 'yylex' initialized and declared 'extern' [enabled by default] extern "C" int yylex(YYSTYPE * lvalp, yyscan_t scanner);


parser.y:13:22: error: 'YYSTYPE' was not declared in this scope


parser.y:13:32: error: 'lvalp' was not declared in this scope extern "C" int yylex(YYSTYPE * lvalp, yyscan_t scanner);


parser.y:13:48: error: expected primary-expression before 'scanner'
 extern "C" int yylex(YYSTYPE * lvalp, yyscan_t scanner);

                                            ^
parser.y:13:55: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 extern "C" int yylex(YYSTYPE * lvalp, yyscan_t scanner);

                                                   ^
parser.tab.c: In function 'int yyparse(yyscan_t, NBloco*)':
parser.tab.c:932:39: error: 'yylex' cannot be used as a function
 # define YYLEX yylex (&yylval, scanner)


parser.tab.c:1618:16: note: in expansion of macro 'YYLEX'
       yychar = YYLEX;
```

// more errors...

I also to fix the yylineno to be per file...
i am basing on http://benlynn.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/reentrant-parsers-with-flex-and-bison.html and http://www.lemoda.net/c/reentrant-parser/index.html

Comment: Why not just pass an instance created in the `main()` scope?

Comment: i added it but i need bison pass it to flex as well...

Comment: Maybe, some small code sample might help to illustrate about your problems. I don't think it's necessary to post the full code here, just the relevant parts, you have problems with in particular.

Comment: Multiple yyparse calls are to support includes? Then did you look at "Multiple Input Buffers" http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Multiple-Input-Buffers? Also why AST to FLEX? Your scanner depends on AST?

Comment: No. it doesnt support includes. it's a IDE with multiple tabs and i want to support to execute multiple tabs at the same time. And well, the flex doesnt really need AST...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, here's a C reentrant flex parser and pure bison example that parses a grammar that matches the following:

```
()
(())
(()())

()()(())()()
```

#### lexer.l

```lex
%option bison-bridge
%option bison-locations
%option ecs
%option nodefault
%option noyywrap
%option reentrant
%option stack
%option warn
%option yylineno

%{
  #include "parser.h"
%}

%%

"(" { return (LPAREN); }
")" { return (RPAREN); }

[ \f\r\t\v\n]+ /* eat whitespace */

%%

/* don't use lexer.l for code, organize it logically elsewhere */
```

#### parser.y

```yacc
%define parse.error verbose
%define api.pure true
%locations
%token-table
%glr-parser
%lex-param {void *scanner}
%parse-param {void *scanner}

%{
/* your top code here */
%}

%union {
  int value; // or whatever else here
}

%token LPAREN
%token RPAREN

%%

document
    : exprs

exprs
    : %empty
    | expr exprs

expr
    : parens

parens
    : LPAREN exprs RPAREN


%%

int
yyerror(YYLTYPE *locp, char *msg) {
  if (locp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "parse error: %s (:%d.%d -> :%d.%d)\n",
                    msg,
                    locp->first_line, locp->first_column,
                    locp->last_line,  locp->last_column
    );
    /* todo: add some fancy ^^^^^ error handling here */
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "parse error: %s\n", msg);
  }
  return (0);
}
```

#### main.c

```c
#include "parser.h"
#include "lexer.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int result;
  yyscan_t scanner;

  yylex_init(&scanner);
  result = (yyparse(scanner));
  yylex_destroy(scanner);
  return (result);
}
```

#### Building

```
flex --header-file=lexer.h --outfile=lexer.c lexer.l
bison --output-file=parser.c --defines=parser.h --warnings=all --feature=all parser.y
cc lexer.c parser.c main.c -o parser
./parser
```

**Note:** OSX's built-in bison is outdated, so install 3.x:

```
brew install bison
```

And then run it like `/usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison ....`

## Now, to migrate to C++

- copy .l to .lxx and .y to .yxx
- change names for output files to *.cxx and *.hxx respectively.

#### lexer.lxx

- add `%option c++`
- remove `reentrant`, `bison-bridge` and `bison-locations`
- change all tokens like the following: `LPAREN` to `yy::parser::token::LPAREN`

#### parser.yxx

- add `%skeleton "lalr1.cc"`
- remove `api.pure`
- remove `yyerror`

#### main.cxx

- rewrite it for C++

Hooking up the lexer and parser objects is an exercise for the reader.

See also: https://github.com/bingmann/flex-bison-cpp-example but beware it uses the old bison 2.x interfaces.

[GNU Bison 3.x C++ Example docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#A-Complete-C_002b_002b-Example)