# Problems with reentrant Flex and Bison

Tags: c, parsing, bison, flex-lexer, reentrancy

I'm learning how to use reentrant Bison and Flex together. I already got a simple calculator working without the reentrant capability. However when I activated the reentrant feature and made the necessary modifications, I couldn't get this to work.

Here is the code:

**scanner.l**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
%}

%option 8bit reentrant bison-bridge
%option warn noyywrap nodefault
%option header-file="lex.yy.h"

DIGIT [0-9]

%%

"+"    { return ADD; }
"-"    { return SUB; }
"*"    { return MUL; }
"/"    { return DIV; }
{DIGIT}+ { *yylval = atof(yytext); return NUM; }
\n     { return EOL; }
[ \t]  {  }
.      { printf("What is this: %s.\n", yytext); }
%%
```

**parser.y**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lex.yy.h"

void yyerror(yyscan_t scanner, char const *msg);
%}

%define api.value.type {double}
%define parse.error verbose
%define api.pure 
%lex-param {yyscan_t scanner}
%parse-param {yyscan_t scanner}

%token NUM EOL                  
%left ADD SUB
%left MUL DIV

%%

input: %empty
| input line
;

line: EOL { printf("|> ");}
| exp EOL { printf("|R> %.4lf\n", $exp); }
;

exp: NUM { $$ = $1; }
| exp ADD exp { $$ = $1 + $3; }
| exp SUB exp { $$ = $1 - $3; }
| exp MUL exp { $$ = $1 * $3; }
| exp DIV exp { $$ = $1 / $3; }
;

%%

void yyerror(yyscan_t scanner, char const *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
#include "lex.yy.h"

int main(void) {

  yyscan_t scanner;

  yylex_init(&scanner);
  yyset_in(stdin, scanner);

  yyparse(scanner);

  yylex_destroy(scanner);

  return 0;
}
```

and this is the `Makefile` I'm using:

```
all: calc.x

parser.tab.c parser.tab.h: parser.y
    bison -d parser.y

lex.yy.c lex.yy.h: scanner.l parser.tab.h
    flex scanner.l

calc.x: lex.yy.c lex.yy.h parser.tab.c parser.tab.h
    gcc main.c parser.tab.c lex.yy.c -o calc.x

clean:
    rm calc.x lex.yy.c lex.yy.h parser.tab.c parser.tab.h *.o
```

Running `make`, I got the following error:

```
In file included from main.c:2:0:
parser.tab.h:66:14: error: unknown type name ‘yyscan_t’
 int yyparse (yyscan_t scanner);
              ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:12:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyparse’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   yyparse(scanner);
   ^
In file included from parser.y:5:0:
lex.yy.h:282:1: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
 YYSTYPE * yyget_lval (yyscan_t yyscanner );
 ^
lex.yy.h:284:18: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
 void yyset_lval (YYSTYPE * yylval_param ,yyscan_t yyscanner );
                  ^
lex.yy.h:332:17: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
                (YYSTYPE * yylval_param ,yyscan_t yyscanner);
                 ^
parser.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
parser.tab.c:1130:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       yychar = yylex (&yylval, scanner);
                ^
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'calc.x' failed
make: *** [calc.x] Error 1
```

But I don't understand the origin of this error and warning messages, for instance:

```
main.c:12:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyparse’
```

But `yyparse` is already defined at `parser.tab.h` and it's being included in `main.c`. Another example:

```
parser.tab.h:66:14: error: unknown type name ‘yyscan_t’
```

And inside `parser.y`, I'm including the scanner header `lex.yy.h`.

I have found these solutions on the Internet:

- [Configuring Bison and Flex without global or static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107203/configuring-bison-and-flex-without-global-or-static-variable)
- [Reentrant parsers with Flex and Bison](http://benlynn.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/reentrant-parsers-with-flex-and-bison.html)
- [Make a reentrant parser with Flex and Bison](http://www.lemoda.net/c/reentrant-parser/)
- [Writing re-entrant lexer with Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634998/writing-re-entrant-lexer-with-flex)
- [Implementing re-entrant parsers in Bison and Flex](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=6341)

But none of them work, resulting in similar errors. If someone could guide me in this quest I'll be grateful.

**Software version**

OS: Debian (testing), Bison: 3.0.4, Flex: 2.5.39, GCC: 5.2.1, Make: 4.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution after tinkering a bit. So the problems arise from a circular dependency between flex and bison.

The parser generated call flex routine in this way:

```
yychar = yylex (&yylval, scanner);
```

So in the bison input we must include the scanner header file `lex.yy.h`
and it's define as:

```
int yylex (YYSTYPE * yylval_param ,yyscan_t yyscanner);
```

But `YYSTYPE` is defined inside the parser header `parser.tab.h`, in my case i said to bison that my type will be `double`:

```
typedef double YYSTYPE;
```

Now the solution. Inside `scanner.l` you must include the parser headers so that flex can return correct tokens (nothing changed).

But inside the `parser.y` you must include both headers file, if you include only the `lex.yy.h` it will complain:

```
lex.yy.h:282:1: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE‘
```

because `YYSTYPE` is defined inside `parser.tab.h`. And finally, for some reason, the bison parser doesn't know what `yyscan_t` even including the lexer header:

```
error: unknown type name ‘yyscan_t’
```

One workaround is defining it to void:

```
%lex-param {void *scanner}
%parse-param {void *scanner}
```

see `yyscan_t` definition: [flex yyscan_t](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/About-yyscan_005ft.html)

So here is the final result:

**scanner.l**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
%}

%option 8bit reentrant bison-bridge
%option warn noyywrap nodefault
%option header-file="lex.yy.h"

//rest of the scanner
```

**parser.y**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
#include "lex.yy.h"

void yyerror(yyscan_t scanner, char const *msg);
%}

%define api.value.type {double}
%define parse.error verbose
%define api.pure 
%lex-param {void *scanner}
%parse-param {void *scanner}

//rest of the input
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "parser.tab.h"
#include "lex.yy.h"

int main(void) {

  yyscan_t scanner;

  yylex_init(&scanner);
  yyset_in(stdin, scanner);

  yyparse(scanner);

  yylex_destroy(scanner);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer by Fabricio Sanches helped me to resolve two issues:

1. `error: unknown type name ‘yyscan_t’` has indeed been solved by changing to `void *`.
2. Conflicts related to circular dependencies dictate **very strict order of imports**:

Your code where Flex/Bison's yyparse is called:

```
#import "parser.h"
#import "lexer.h"
```

Flex (Lexer.lm):

```
%{
#import "parser.h"
%}
```

Bison (Parser.ym):

```
%{
#import "parser.h"
#import "lexer.h"
%}
```

---

I have written blog post about the process of creation of reentrant parser using Flex and Bison on Mac OS with example of its integration to Xcode project: [Reentrant parser using Flex and Bison](http://stanislaw.github.io/2016/03/29/reentrant-parser-using-flex-and-bison.html).

Comment: Question: I have your setup working from your linked blog. Could you explain why I can't include files like "#include <iostream>" ?

Comment: No rush. Just reading your blog etc... I want to create a compiler in Xcode. Or put another way, I want to develop something using Flex/Bison within Xcode - that will also make use of C++ STL

Comment: Rename .lm to .lmm and .ym to .ymm and update Makefile accordingly. This should let Xcode know about your intention to use Clang++.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127014/discussion-between-dylan-larkin-and-stanislav-pankevich).